# Most efficient way to search large dataset for item

Tags: c#, linq, search, dataset, processing-efficiency

This has probably been asked before but I have not been able to find the same scenario.

I have been given a huge SQL dataset of a single column of strings (ie. Cities containing branches of a company).

I have also been given an even larger master dataset of strings (ie. All the cities in the world).

The first dataset changes every day. I need to run through this every single day to check whether every string can be found in the master dataset.

I have no control over the design of either dataset.

I have tried:

```
Foreach (cityRow in dailyDS.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     DataRow[] row = masterDs.Tables[0].Select("City like '%" + (string)cityRow["City"] + "%'");
}
```

and using linq (considerably faster than the select statement)

```
Foreach (cityRow in dailyDS.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     DataRow existingRow = masterDs.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<string>("City") == (string)cityRow["City"]).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The entire aim of my program is to produce a list of cities where there is currently a company branch that are NOT in the master city list (ie, they have been spelt wrong etc.) I have written the program but just wanted to know:

**What is the MOST efficient way to search for exact values in a dataset like this?**

Comment: You can load city strings from both `DataSet` to a `HashSet<string>` and if you are looking for exact match , then simply do `companyCityHashSet.Except(AllCitiesHashSet).Any()`, Not really sure if you would get any performance improvement but you can try.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks! Currently there are over 23,000 rows in the company city dataset!

Comment: that is not a lot. I am not sure what is going on in your code, but that shouldn't take much time.

Comment: Using linq is considerably faster, it was the select statement that was causing the most delay, I'm still wondering if there was something faster than linq

Comment: update your question with your LINQ code, also I am not sure what is your exact requirement, Are you just interested if your branch Cities exists in all cities DataSet ? Are you interested in other fields from the `DataSet` ? What is your exact requirement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it really fast, you must load all cities of the world into a `HashSet<string>`.

Then for each cityOfCompany check if the `HashSet.Contains(cityOfCompany)`

With just 23k strings to check this should run few seconds on a modern PC.

Comment: Took me a long time to convert the list of datarows into a list of strings, but having finally done it... that's speedy! Thanks!